# Limit of sequence using mean value

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let $f(x)=1-\frac{x}{10}$ and define the sequence $(a_n)$ by:
\begin{align}
& a_0 = 0, \\
& a_{n+1} = f(a_n), \text{ for } n\geq 0.
\end{align}
I found $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) = x_0$ which turned out to be $\frac{10}{11}$.

Prove that $\lim a_n = x_0$.

I tried using $\frac{a_{n+1}-x_0}{a_n-x_0}$ and $\frac{a_{n+2}-x_0}{a_{n+1}-x_0}$ to show that the second one was smaller than the first but I got stuck and couldn't simplify to a reasonable form where it was apparent that one was smaller than the other.  Is there another reasonable approach?  Possibly using $\frac{a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}}{a_{n+1}-a_n}$?

Answer (score 1):

You have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac {(-1)^k}{10^k} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {1-\left(\frac {-1} {10}\right)^n}{1-\frac {-1} {10}}= \frac {10} {11}$$

Comment: Because in the base case, $a_0=0$, I we have to make a separate case for that and then for everything greater than n=0, this sum should be lim of n+1 because when n=1, you should get 1 by the function in the question so you want the k to be 0, or n-1 in that case.  , I believe.

Comment: Thanks, though it was still technically correct as it was in the limit. :P For n=0 it is still true as the empty sum is defined to be 0

Answer (score 0):

Since
\begin{align}
& |a_{n + 1} - a_n| = |f(a_n) - f(a_{n - 1})| \\
= & \left|\left(1 - \frac{1}{10}a_n\right) - \left(1 - \frac{1}{10}a_{n - 1}\right)\right| \\
= & \frac{1}{10}|a_n - a_{n - 1}|,
\end{align}
$f$ is a contraction. And the result follows from the contraction principle.